# How can I find out which angular directive parent is closer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a angularjs directive as a child directive to multiple of my other directives, rather then having a separate child directive for each parent directive. All the parent directives expose the same controller functions, so the child directive can call the them regardless of which one of them is the parent.

To do this I know I have to require all my parent directive in my single child directive.

```
... require: ['?^parent1', '?^parent2', '?^parent3', '?^parent4', '?^parent5'] ...
```

In my child directive link function I'll get an array of the possible parent directive controllers.

```
... link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrls) {} ...
```

Lets say I have my parent directives nested for some reason.

```
<parent3><parent5><child></child></parent5></parent3>
```

When I console.log the "ctrls" varable from the link function I get this:

```
ctrls => [null, null, Object, null, Object]
```

How can I determine which controller is from the closest parent ?

PS - I hope I made my self clear, if not please ask for clarification :)

Comment: Frankly speaking, seems like a design flaw if you need as many controllers and don't know their order in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a design flaw, but I see it's not the "angular way"... I could just put a target property to the child directive scope but was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: i look for same thing :| i naturally define both x and data-x attributes when i define a directive, and i look for knowing which of my containers are closer, if the user defined both container and data-container directive :|